# I wrote this code using JsPDF but doesn't seems to work at all. What is should I use to make this work?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jspdf

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Generate PDF from Text</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Generate PDF from Text</h1>
  
  <textarea id="textInput" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea>
  <br>
  <button id="downloadBtn">Download as PDF</button>
  
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/2.5.1/jspdf.umd.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    document.getElementById("downloadBtn").addEventListener("click", function() {
      var text = document.getElementById("textInput").value;
      
      // Create a new jsPDF instance
      var doc = new jsPDF();
      
      // Set the font size and add the text to the PDF
      doc.setFontSize(12);
      doc.text(text, 10, 10);
      
      // Download the PDF file
      doc.save("my_pdf.pdf");
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to acheive it so that the when I click the button, it allows me download a PDF file containing the things I wrote in the textarea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative way of defining jsPDF as a page constant is like this, however note that web security will not let these snippets run in Stack Overflow pages, they need to be used in your own environment.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Generate PDF from Text</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Generate PDF from Text</h1>
  
  <textarea id="textInput" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea>
  <br>
  <button id="downloadBtn">Download as PDF</button>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/2.5.1/jspdf.umd.min.js" integrity="sha512-qZvrmS2ekKPF2mSznTQsxqPgnpkI4DNTlrdUmTzrDgektczlKNRRhy5X5AAOnx5S09ydFYWWNSfcEqDTTHgtNA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    <script>
    document.getElementById("downloadBtn").addEventListener("click", function() {


      // Create a new jsPDF instance
      const {jsPDF} = window.jspdf;
      var doc = new jsPDF();
      var text = document.getElementById("textInput").value;
      
      // Set the font size and add the text to the PDF
      doc.setFontSize(12);
      doc.text(text, 10, 10);
      
      // Download the PDF file
      doc.save("my_pdf.pdf");
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

NOTE that in common with the way NATIVE PDF works there is no line wrap since text cannot be natively wrapped by a PDF

[image]

what you would need is to hardware key-in an enter at EOL (end of line)
[image]

With a few more bits of styling it makes for a good Notes.PDF generator especially if using a courier font for programmers code copying.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this line at the beginning of your script:

```
window.jsPDF = window.jspdf.jsPDF;
```

The final code:

```html
<h1>Generate PDF from Text</h1>

    <textarea id="textInput" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea>
    <br>
    <button id="downloadBtn">Download as PDF</button>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/2.5.1/jspdf.umd.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        window.jsPDF = window.jspdf.jsPDF;

        document.getElementById("downloadBtn").addEventListener("click", function () {
            var text = document.getElementById("textInput").value;

            // Create a new jsPDF instance
            var doc = new jsPDF();

            // Set the font size and add the text to the PDF
            doc.setFontSize(12);
            doc.text(text, 10, 10);

            // Download the PDF file
            doc.save("my_pdf.pdf");
        });
    </script>
```